# powershell, check a backup directory and delete old ones only if there is more than one file

Tags: powershell

Hello to the whole community, I am trying to inspect directories and subdirectories of a folder and if one of them gets more than one file if it has more than 15 days to delete it and leave only the most updated.

but I still do not get the way that if I get a single file despite having more than 15 days old do not touch it as long as there is one more updated within the same directory.

I am currently working with this code

```
$timeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) 
Get-ChildItem D:\backup\OldFilesTemp -Directory | where LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit  | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

grateful for the support they can give me.

Comment: Can you give an example of tree file before and after delete?

Comment: Yep, question is really confusing on what you are trying to achieve. First part says if you find more than 1 file in a folder, delete all files more than 15 days old and only leave the most updated one. Which means you can only leave 1 file? Second part says you need to leave one intact along with an updated one?

Comment: Tell me if I understood this correctly? You are trying to setup a backup solution where 1.) You need backup files for the last 15 days and delete the rest
2.) If there is only 1 backup file in the last 15 days, keep the most recent of all other backup files as insurance and delete the rest.
is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Looks like your current code is going to delete folders instead of files.

Comment: Really thank you for your answers.

I will explain in more detail so that it is understood better.

I have the following file tree:

Main directory: D: \ Backup \ Files

Within the main directory are the following subdirectories: 

DirectoryA1
SubdirectoryA1
FileA1
FileA2
FileA3

SubdirectoryB2
FileB1
FileB2
FileB3

SubdirectoryC3
FileA1

Assuming that files 2 and 3 are older than file 1 then delete file 2 and 3 and keep file 1.

In case of subdirectoryC3 has a single file, but even though it is old as it is the only one it has does not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

`$timeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) 
Get-ChildItem D:\backup\OldFilesTemp | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_ | Where-Object { -not $PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit } | Remove-Item -Force }`

Replace `Remove-Item -Force` with `Remove-Item -WhatIf` to perform a dry run.

Comment: Try running it by changing the days value to 0 to do the tests now and do not wait 15 days but do not delete anything :(

Comment: How deep is your folder structure?

Comment: 5 level more or less

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeLimit = ([System.DateTime]::Today).AddDays(-15) #Dont use Get-Date.
$BackupFolder = "D:\backup\OldFilesTemp"
$FolderList = Get-ChildItem $BackupFolder -Directory -Recurse | Select FullName

Foreach ($Folder in $FolderList)
{
    $FileList = Get-ChildItem $Folder -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending
    $Count = ($FileList | Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -GE $timeLimit).Count

    #Keep an old file if there is only 1 or no recent backups
    if ($Count -le 1)
    {
        $FileList | Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT $timeLimit | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force
    }
    else
    {
        $FileList | Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT $timeLimit | Remove-Item -Force
    }
}
```

Better do your testing before you deploy on your environment.

Comment: Try running it by changing the days value to 0 to do the tests now and do not wait 15 days but do not delete anything :(

Comment: copy your entire backup or make a replica of it somewhere else and run the script on that folder to see if it is working like you expected. Just Change `$BackupFolder = "D:\backup\OldFilesTemp"` to the testing directory

Comment: I did it with a test directory but it did not work, but in the course of the day I'm going to do other tests and if it works, I'll comment on what code I used and what I did to make it work. Thank you all for your time.